# AIX swap usage shows ~20%, not even close to maximum load

Tags: memory, swap, aix

I got an alarm that my swap usage was up to 80%, which turned to be a fact when I checked `topas`.

The problems I've found were:

1) Looking into a `vmstat 5 10`, I found lots of PIs with *0* SRs. How's that even possible?

```
kthr    memory              page              faults              cpu
----- ----------- ------------------------ ------------ -----------------------
r   b   avm    fre    re  pi  po  fr   sr  cy  in   sy    cs    us sy id wa    pc    ec
12  1 12245252 92621   0 229   0   0    0   0 1884 56260  24568 84 15  0  0  2.50  99.9
12  1 12245413 90313   0 190   0   0    0   0 1764 51759  23827 86 14  0  0  2.50  99.9
12  1 12245193 88040   0 218   0   0    0   0 1734 69307  25347 85 15  0  0  2.50  99.9
14  1 12246377 83810   0 157   0   0    0   0 1960 80471  24057 84 16  0  0  2.50 100.0
13  1 12246050 79785   0 183   0   0    0   0 2280 103138 21990 81 19  0  0  2.50 100.0
12  1 12245988 77393   0 173   0   0    0   0 1881 51984  22331 84 16  0  0  2.50 100.0
14  1 12246180 74721   0 179   0   0    0   0 1792 52624  20610 79 21  0  0  2.50  99.9
15  1 12246131 72304   0 176   0   0    0   0 2109 58504  23344 82 18  0  0  2.50  99.9
15  1 12246673 68231   0 187   0   0    0   0 2272 73068  25319 85 15  0  0  2.50  99.9
13  1 12246305 66342   0 172   0   0    0   0 1966 104313 21884 83 17  0  0  2.50 100.0
```

2) I went off to find who were consuming my precious memory and it I found that I actually know very little in how to figure that in a AIX.

Found this command somewhere which seemed reasonable reading the manual:

```
 ps -ealf | head -1 ; ps -ealf | sort -rn +9 | head
```

which seemed reasonable by looking in the manual and gave an output of the sort:

```
F      S   UID       PID   PPID   C PRI NI ADDR        SZ    STIME     TTY   TIME CMD
242001 A  util   1581080      1  76  60 20 fb34510 150044 10:55:40   pts/0 103:43 /usr...
242001 A  util    569540      1   0  60 20 d235510 142580 11:01:09   pts/0  68:55 /usr/...
242001 A  util   1425464      1   4  60 20 43c6510 129916 23:17:58       - 168:02 /usr...
202001 A  util    245864      1  83  60 24 da9e510 113008 13:37:22   pts/2  43:26 /usr/...
242001 A  util   1163370      1   0  68 24 d69d510 103572 09:55:52  pts/13  17:24 /usr/...
242001 A  util    466984      1   0  60 20 5d0c510 83064  11:00:34   pts/0  22:57 /usr/...
242001 A  raid   1048782      1   7  60 20 e5b8510 78724  16:41:18   pts/6   0:36 /usr/...
242001 A  util    659612      1  13  60 20 edc3510 76400  11:13:17   pts/0  10:57 /usr/...
242001 A  util   1134736      1   0  60 20 eb91510 75188  06:21:23       -  27:23 /usr/...
```

Where SZ is supposed to be the size in 1k units, according to the man page; which also didn't make too much sense for  these are Java processes with Xms=1G (or so) and as shown the biggest process has ~150mb. Again.. ?

And for the last, my server is not currently at maximum load but still shows ~20% of swap space usage. How do I explain that?

I'm pretty lost. These things were easier to figure with Solaris.

Would someone share some thoughts?

Comment: Can you display the VSZ for each process as well as/instead of the SZ?  e.g. `ps -o pid,ppid,sz,vsz`?

Comment: You also didn't say how much RAM and swap the system had.  Try running `lsps -s`.

Answer (score 1):

What are your vmm settings settings ?

Make sure you have lru_file_repage=1.

```
vmo -o lru_file_repage
```

The default setting (lru_file_repage=0) has the effect that AIX pages out application pages, even if there are plenty of cached files around where pages could be thrown away. One effect is a growing paging space use.

The setting lru_file_repage=0 is the default up and including AIX 5.3